# Do Camel and Moose carry any significance when dreamt of, as per Hinduism?

Tags: animals, dream

Are Camel and Moose vahanas of any specific deity?

Comment: Moose are not native to Asia....

Comment: Camel is vahana for Hanuman. Not sure for whom moose is the Vahana. Anyways, these dreams can definitely have some significance as per Hinduism

Comment: Swami Vishwananda, nice to hear from you!! I am your fan, especially your song 'Mere Thakur Govinda, thakurani Radhe!" Thank you for the reply. Thank you, Rickross for your reply. I was wondering if Camel signified planet/node Rahu and Moose signified Ketu (the North node). I will research further. Many thanks.

Comment: @JRD Goat (ChAga) is related to Ketu. Camel may be related to Rahu, as it's found in deserts and sand is definitely linked to Rahu.

Answer (score 2):

Camel is the vAhana of one of the goddess named dashA mA which is popularly venerated in the region of Gujarat.

There are legends, vratas, and festivals associated with the goddess.

> One of the most popular mother goddess cults in Gujarat is the cult of
>   Dasha Maa. The goddess is worshipped mainly by the people of the
>   suppressed class Hindus.
>
> In the month of Shravan the women folk of the state representing
>   mostly the lower strata of the society observe a ten days vrat (a vrat
>   is a penance undertaken as a ritual occasion and calls for fasting,
>   prayer often for a particular boon, and ritual worship according to
>   set rules – at such times stories appropriate to the religious
>   occasion, with the deity concerned appearing as a figure in the tale,
>   are told by an older woman to a group of women) in the honour of Dasha
>   Maa, and also in the honour of other folk deities: Nagbai Maa and
>   Momai Maa. A small statue is made of these mother goddesses, to which
>   chandalo (sandalwood paste and kanku), and puja is offered daily. The
>   image is immersed on the tenth day. During this period women pray for
>   the improvement of their dasha or condition, perhaps their economic
>   well being or health. They wear a thread with ten knots, and each day
>   one knot is united. The worshipper lives on one meal a day and the
>   food is made of wheat. Dasama stories are told in the morning, and in
>   the evening women dance the garba. Men do not participate in any of
>   this.

[Source](http://indiahistoryspeaks.blogspot.ca/2008/08/vrat-of-dasha-maa-in-gujarat.html?m=1)